# Avoid Z-Fighting when drawing badminton / tennis court on a floor, or graffiti on a wall - using three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, aframe

I am creating a representation of a gym / sports club using three.js (and a-frame). I've positioned some badminton courts in the relevant places, with the floor lines and a net (very simple proof of concept) but when moving around the scene, the lines on the floor flicker.

I've read up on this and it seems to be due to z-fighting, where two objects occupy the same point in space, and fight over their own visibility. I was hoping that just adding 1mm to the Y axis (i.e. lifting the lines very slightly above the floor) would mean that they no longer occupy the same space.

However, doing this only has a very limited benefit, and when moving away from the court, it starts to flicker again, I think due to the 1mm being deemed as irrelevant once it is more than a few metres away (I'm making up those numbers).

If I move the line 10mm (or 100mm) above the floor, then they only start flickering once I'm a 'long' way away, but then they don't look correct when close-up.

Is there a way of avoiding this? Maybe by giving one of the objects a 'priority' or something.

I might be missing something obvious here, and I've looked at the answers to some similar questions, but a lot of those questions are from 7-8 years ago, so was hoping there might be some more up to date solutions to this.

I temporarily got around this by creating a 'negative' plane of the floor excluding the court lines (using multiple planes), then painting the actual court lines in the gaps. This works nicely, but is very fiddly and if I want to add a texture to the floor, it would be difficult to create this 'negative' plane. If I didn't explain that well, imagine cutting a circle out of a sheet of paper, then putting a new circle of a different colour in that gap.

Comment: "long way" may suggest depth buffer issues. Did you try switching to a [logarithmic depth buffer](https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/renderer.html#logarithmicdepthbuffer)? Would be easier to debug with a sample glitch.